# How to get 2 dataset to compare in a visual using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a dataset I have broken into 2 specific views

One showing:

```
by_pd = date_mask.groupby(['director_primary'],sort=False).aggregate({'release_date':'count','gross_profit':'sum'})
```

```
top_20_grossing = by_pd.sort_values(by='gross_profit', ascending=False)[:20]
```

```
                   films_released  gross_profit
director_primary                             
Peter Jackson                 8    5202593685
David Yates                   5    3379295625
Christopher Nolan             8    3162548502
J.J. Abrams                   5    2839169916
Michael Bay                   8    2760938960
Steven Spielberg             11    2659994241
James Cameron                 3    2548546718
Francis Lawrence              6    2476979588
Joss Whedon                   5    2424263144
Gore Verbinski                8    2271362290
Sam Raimi                     6    2254066354
Carlos Saldanha               5    2169451792
Ridley Scott                 13    2109601581
Andrew Adamson                6    1991859447
Chris Columbus                6    1888968952
James Wan                     8    1813662186
Tim Burton                   10    1801663457
Sam Mendes                    6    1708252208
Brad Bird                     5    1581913958
Shawn Levy                   11    1515787063
```

And one showing:

```
by_pd2 = df.groupby(['director_primary'],sort=False).aggregate({'release_date':'count','gross_profit':'sum'})
```

```
top_20_grossing_all = by_pd2.sort_values(by='gross_profit', ascending=False)[:20]
```

```
                   films_released  gross_profit
director_primary                             
Steven Spielberg             29    7428613772
Peter Jackson                13    5196468949
James Cameron                11    5081849077
Michael Bay                  11    3557208171
David Yates                   5    3379295625
Chris Columbus               14    3224491668
Christopher Nolan            10    3162548502
George Lucas                  6    2955996893
Robert Zemeckis              17    2843990869
J.J. Abrams                   5    2839169916
Tim Burton                   20    2629549685
Francis Lawrence              6    2476979588
Joss Whedon                   5    2424263144
Roland Emmerich              11    2406825574
Gore Verbinski                9    2355779679
Ron Howard                   22    2274471847
Sam Raimi                    14    2240870360
Carlos Saldanha               5    2169451792
Ridley Scott                 23    2167096480
Sam Mendes                    7    2049548809
```

The idea was to compare the different sets to see if the amount of films they make impacts the gross profit significantly more than just having a few high grossing films.

I have attempted to use the bar chart functions from matplotlib but I am not sure why they aren't working. Honestly, matplotlib is very new to me and I am not sure if there is a better visual I can utilize.

Originally I tried the following code but clearly I am not understanding how it functions and was only initially trying to see if I could just get it to work so I could figure out how to actually use it.

```
width = 0.25  # the width of the bars
multiplier = 0

fig, ax = mt.subplots(layout='constrained')

for attribute, measurement in top_20_grossing_all.items():
    offset = width * multiplier
    rects = ax.bar(x + offset, measurement, width, label=attribute)
    ax.bar_label(rects, padding=3)
    multiplier += 1

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Flims Released Count')
ax.set_title('Profit vs Film Count per Director')
ax.set_xticks(x + width, top_20_grossing_all['director_primary'])
ax.legend(loc='upper left', ncols=3)
ax.set_ylim(0, 250)

mt.show()
```

Some direction on what I am misunderstanding would be very helpful. Or pointing me into the best direction for the type of visual that would actually work.

Comment: Maybe a scatter plot? Number of movies on the X-axis, profit on the Y-axis, different hue/color for each dataset

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into sub plotting. Sub plotting allows you to have 2 or more different plots next to each other. To make a subplot all you have to say is `plt.sublot(n,m,plot_number)`. The whole screen is going to be divided to n cols and m rows. In every little box that get created as a result, there is going to be a little subplot. Every sublot will get plotted in one of those little boxes according to it's plot_number. I think you are going to understand this better with an example.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# define how many columns and rows your sublots are going to take up 
cols,rows = 2,1

x1 = [1,2,3,4]
y1 = [1,2,3,4]
# make a sublot and place it at the 1st index
plt.subplot(cols,rows,1)
# plot what you want in the subplot
plt.plot(x1,y1)

x2 = [1,2,4,5]
y2 = [1,2,3,4]
# make a sublot and place it at the 2nd index
plt.subplot(cols,rows,2)
# plot what you want in the subplot
plt.plot(x2,y2)

plt.show()
```

the result:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried a subplot prior but it wouldn't work. I will look into it a bit more because I think I get where you are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to "*see if the amount of films they make impacts the gross profit*", you could plot a scatter plot with two different colors/markers, this gives you an idea of the dispersion of the data in the two dimensions:

```
ax = top_20_grossing.plot.scatter(x='films_released', y='gross_profit',
                                  label='top_20_grossing', color='r', marker='+')
top_20_grossing_all.plot.scatter(x='films_released', y='gross_profit',
                                 label='top_20_grossing_all', color='b', marker='x', ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling on what to use and how to approach it since I haven't before. I really like the scatter plot but worried my data set was too small for something like this.